# SQLite: manipulating one column into two columns of pairs

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to calculate the distances (difference between squared longitudinal coordinates) between all airports by using SQLite. One column consists of all the airports, and another is all the longitudinal coordinates. My thought is for each airport (there are 322), I need to have a second column for a pair with every other airport (i.e. if I have one column with ATL, LAX, JFK, and LGA, then I need 6 rows and two columns with ATL/LAX, ATL/LGA, ATL/JFK, LAX/LGA, LAX/JFK, LGA/JFK).

Can anyone give me some of advice how to code this in SQLite? Or if there is a better approach to calculating distances for each pair?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able self join on the table, making what is called a cartesian product, given a table with two columns `airport_code` and `airport_location` the SQL would look like this:

```
select a.airport_code, 
       a.airport_location, 
       b.airport_code, 
       b.airport_location
from   airport_table a join airport_table b
where  a.airport_code <> b.airport_code
```